# NullPointerException while checking logged in user

Tags: java

I am trying to check if a user is logged in by checking if there's a value stored in the session :

```
String userId = null;
if(session.getAttribute("user_id")!=null){
    userId=(String)session.getAttribute("user_id");
}

if(userId!=null||!userId.isEmpty()){
    //do something
}
```

But I am getting a NullPointerException at this line : `if(userId!=null||!userId.isEmpty())` when the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `&&`:

```
if (userId!=null && !userId.isEmpty()) {
```

If you used `||`, then Java will evaluate both conditions anyway, regardless of the truth values of either expression.  So if you used `||`, then even though `userId` is null, Java will go ahead and try to evaluate `!userId.isEmpty()`, which gives you the `NullPointerException`.

By using `&&`, if the first condition is false, then Java knows that the expression is already false and there is no point in proceeding.  So in this case, if `userId` was null, then `userId!=null` is false, and Java skips the body of the `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference :)

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is incorrect; you need `&&` (logical-and) instead of `||` (logical-or) to properly short-circuit your condition.

```
if(userId!=null && !userId.isEmpty()){
```

This way, `userId.isEmpty()` won't be executed -- and won't throw a `NullPointerException` -- if `userId` is null.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    if( session.isOpened())
    {
      if(user!=null)
       {
         //do here whatever
       }
    }
```

Comment: This one is for facebook. Misunderstood your question
use if (userId!=null&&!userId.isEmpty()). Imagine a situation where userId is null in OR case it goes to later statement and u running a function with null object id which gives u nullPointerException